# Module-like inclusion of Structs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, struct, module

So I tried some code like the following:

```
ComplicatedClass
  module InternalObjects
    InternalThing = Struct.new(:name, :description)
  end
end

class ComplicatedClass
  module Operations
    def operate_on_object
      InternalThing.new
    end
  end
end

class ComplicatedClass
  include InternalObjects
  include Operations

  def other_operate_on_object
    InternalThing.new
  end
end
```

Then with `cc = ComplicatedClass.new`, `cc.other_operate_on_object` works just fine, but calling `cc.operate_on_object` causes a `NameError: uninitialized constant ComplicatedClass::Operations::InternalThing`

Clearly I can just choose to not have an `InternalObjects` module and just define my Structs in `ComplicatedClass`:

```
class ComplicatedClass
  InternalThing = Struct.new(:name, :description)
  include Operations

  def other_operate_on_object
    InternalThing.new
  end
end
```

and not have a problem, but then it's obnoxious to reuse the same Struct elsewhere (and probably leads to metaprogramming in an initialization routine as a workaround).

Likewise, I could also namespace the `new` call in the Operations module (`ComplicatedClass::InternalThing.new`), but it'd be extremely ill-advised from a code-reuse standpoint IMO.

- Is there a way to define a Struct in a module such that you can just include the module in a class, and then have methods included from other modules be able to use said Struct?
- Even if you can, is this a bad idea?
- If I have a handful of Structs I reuse with some frequency throughout my application is there a proper way to define them in a module-like way? Or is there a different approach I should be taking?
- Is metaprogramming actually my best bet?
- Or even if they're very very
  very very dumb objects should I be making them into their own
  full-blown classes?

Comment: I don't see how it's ill-advised from a code-reuse perspective to namespace the `new` call. That's how constant lookup works. Even if you defined `InternalThing` in the `ComplicatedClass::Operations` namespace, you'd still need to say `self.class::InternalThing` from `#operate_on_object` because it's an instance method. Constants do not become shared even if their parent module is included/extended. Actually it's sometimes advised to use static methods / namespaces because it's easier to refactor (granted, the opposite is sometimes recommended too)

Comment: I think on some level InternalThing being a class constant didn't really register, and that "oh duh" moment has made things a lot clearer. Thanks!